# Youtube-dl Playlists Downloading Stops Running “Finished downloading playlist: playlist” error

Tags: youtube-dl, playlist

I was happily downloading channels playlists but out of the blue youtube-dl detects any channel playlists as fully downloaded. I can download videos and playlists but no channels playlists.

Desired behavior: youtube-dl downloading all playlists of a choosen channel.

Specific problem or error: youtube-dl detects all playlists as already downloaded and it downloads 0 videos.

Code necessary to reproduce de problem:

```
youtube-dl -i https://www.youtube.com/c/MentalOutlaw/playlists
```

Result:

```
[youtube:playlists] MentalOutlaw: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Mental Outlaw
[youtube:playlists] playlist Mental Outlaw: Downloading 0 videos
[download] Finished downloading playlist: Mental Outlaw
```

I've tried removing yt-dl and reinstalling from another repo. Restarting computer. Tried different directories and different channels. Thing is I did it before but all of a sudden it stops doing it.

OSPop!_OS 20.04 LTS

```
youtube-dl version 2020.09.20
```

Answer (score 6):

Issue is fixed in the latest release [2020.11.18](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/releases/tag/2020.11.18). (Related Issue: [#26952](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/))

[pypi](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/) has the latest version `pip install youtube_dl`

Comment: Note: I couldn't see the updated version in Apt Repository yet.

Answer (score 2):

I had also received this message while downloading videos from private playlist (it gets updated few times a month, and I have the same script that worked for a long time), these steps helped(**do not use apt as it can receive updated later than pip version**):

```
pip3 install youtube-dl --upgrade
```

To install the latest version of youtube-dl, then I updated my cookies file, because they had expired

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the python source, updated on GitLab. There is an extractor for each supported platform. One of them youtube.py has a class called YoutubePlaylistIE (YoutubePlaylistBaseInfoExtractor), I didn’t have time to look more deeply into the process of downloading the playlist, but whoever can already know a way.

https://gitlab.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/-/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py

Comment: The yt-dl repository has returned, but they have not yet been able to analyze which functions will be discontinued.
https://github.blog/2020-11-16-standing-up-for-developers-youtube-dl-is-back

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this is a new issue caused due to Google changing stuff on youtube and has not been updated by ytdl yet. Look in to the following [github issue](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/26952) for more info.
Your best bet right now is to download each playlist separately unfortunately (:

P.S. Maybe try downgrading your youtube-dl to a lower version and it might work, i don't think it will though.

Comment: I'm also having this issue and I tried random versions as far back as `2017.1.2` and it still didn't work.

Comment: I'm also getting the same issue, with v2020.03.24 on Ubuntu 20.04.1